# java.util.MissingResourceException when using jasperreport 5.2.0 within an plugin project

Tags: java, jasper-reports, rcp

I'm working on an rcp project and we use jasperreports version 5.2.0.

When performing JasperFillManager.fillReport a MissingResourceException is thrown by jasper reports.

```
java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name hwreport, locale en_US
at java.util.ResourceBundle.throwMissingResourceException(ResourceBundle.java:1427)
at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1250)
at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(ResourceBundle.java:952)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRResourcesUtil.loadResourceBundle(JRResourcesUtil.java:660)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRResourcesUtil.loadResourceBundle(JRResourcesUtil.java:598)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.loadResourceBundle(JRFillDataset.java:570)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.setParameterValues(JRFillDataset.java:605)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.setParameters(JRBaseFiller.java:1280)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:900)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:864)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fill(JRFiller.java:88)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:653)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:969)
```

The needed resources are located on the classpath and its possible to load the resources directly from the plugin. However jasperreports does not.

Previously we used version 4.0.1 and it worked fine.

Does anyone know how to fix this?